# Artifactory cannot resolve plugin artifact without version

Tags: maven, netbeans, artifactory, resolve

I have an artifactory repository which works great except for resolving org.apache.maven.plugins artifacts. Whenever I try to compile a NetBeans project it keeps giving this exception for all of the maven plugins used in my project.

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Developer\.m2\repository), central (http://my.example.com/artifactory/plugins-release), snapshots (http://my.example.com/artifactory/plugins-release)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

I assume it is because NetBeans does not specify a version of these plugins because it will always try to use the latest. How can I get my Artifactory to resolve these artifacts?

Comment: Have you tried it with explicit versions as well?

Comment: How do I specify a version? When I use the build command from NetBeans it issues the command: cd C:\Projects\MyMavenProject; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_80" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Software\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Software\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install\""

Comment: Two possibilities: You can set the versions of plugins in the `<pluginManagement>` section of your POM or you can call an explicit goal (I guess that Netbeans allows you to execute arbitrary maven goals).

Comment: How does the maven central repository resolve these artifacts without a version? Because it works if I remove my settings.xml file to bypass my artifactory repository.

Comment: without version, Maven uses the highest version. But have you tried to run it with a specified version?

Comment: Yes if I specify a version in <pluginManagement> it works, but I would like to configure my artifactory to resolve it the same as maven central.

Answer (score 0):

It might be necessary to expose a Maven index

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Exposing+Maven+Indexes

Comment: I have added maven indexes but still no joy. The maven-install-plugin still fails.